# prevent msys shell from translating path-like strings

Tags: msys

I'm trying to use docker for windows in msys

```
docker run -v /c/some/dir:/inside/container ...
```

gets munged into

```
c:\\some\\dir;c:\\msys\\inside\\container ...
```

How do i disable the translation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL`, see https://github.com/msys2/msys2/wiki/Porting

Comment: The URL in this answer now redirects to https://www.msys2.org/wiki/Porting/ - but I won't try to edit it in while the moderation strike is ongoing.